# Openlayer3 basemap appears white block in Chrome

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript

i faced interesting an issue on Chrome. im using google's 4 number base layer (street, hybrit, etc.) When my tiles are loading over baselayer, baseLayer becomes white block. Why?

No any issues on Firefox and IE8 or IE9.

```
 var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        projection: 'EPSG:900913',
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Physical",
                { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN }
            ),
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Streets",
                { numZoomLevels: 20 }
            ),
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Hybrid",
                { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 20 }
            ),
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Satellite",
                { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 20 }
            )
        ],
        center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(35.5, 39.0)
            .transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")),
        zoom: 7
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know the side effects but it fixed, when "olTileImage" override in style.css file that incoming from  openLayer.js

```
 img.olTileImage {
      -webkit-transform:inherit;
    -moz-transform: inherit;
    -o-transform:inherit ;
    -ms-transform: inherit;
    transform:inherit ;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: inherit;
    -moz-backface-visibility:inherit ;
    -ms-backface-visibility:inherit ;
    backface-visibility:inherit ;
    -webkit-perspective:inherit ;
    -moz-perspective:inherit ;
    -ms-perspective:inherit ;
    perspective:inherit ;

}
```